# how to mock method retry and variable assignment inside method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
require 'requiredclass'

class Test
  def get_client()
    return some_client
  end

  def intermediate_method()
    res = nil
    self.class
      .get_client
      .retry(tries:5, on: [RequiredClass::ClientTimeout]) do |myclient|
         call_count += 1
         res = myclient.dosomething()
      end
  
    return res
  end

  def method_to_test()
    x = intermediate_method()
    y = false
    return x && y
  end
end
```

How can I write rspec for `method_to_test` here. How can I mock `get_client.retry` as well as calls to `get_client` while also mocking `res` variable assignment so that gets assigned the value i would like it to assign.

Answer (score 0):

As written, this code is difficult to test. That's a smell and a sign that the code should be restructured. Really any time you feel tempted to mock a method in the current class, that's a sign that the thing you want to mock does not belong in that class. It should be injected (passed in) instead. Like this:

```
require 'requiredclass'

class Test
  attr_reader :client

  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
  end

  def method_to_test
    x = intermediate_method
    y = false
    x && y
  end

  def intermediate_method
    res = nil
    client.retry(tries: 5, on: [RequiredClass:ClientTimeout]) do |my_client|
      call_count += 1
      res = my_client.do_something
    end
    res
  end
end
```

Given this refactored code, the tests might look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Test do
  subject(:test) { Test.new(client) }

  let(:client) { instance_double(Client, retry: true, do_something: true) }

  describe '#method_to_test'
    subject(:method_to_test) { test.method_to_test }

    it 'returns false' do
      expect(method_to_test).to be_false
    end
  end
end
```

In this code I've passed a double with a stubbed `retry` method into the Test class on instantiation. You could optionally use a mock, instead. That would look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Test do
  subject(:test) { Test.new(client) }

  let(:client) { instance_double(Client) }

  before do
    allow(client).to receive(:retry)
    allow(client).to receive(:do_something)
  end

  describe '#method_to_test'
    subject(:method_to_test) { test.method_to_test }

    it 'returns false' do
      expect(method_to_test).to be_false
    end
  end
end
```

There's a good write up of mocks and doubles in the [RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs).